# How can I run latest RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^where-is-german-spoken$ default-template.php?page_id=4  [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^where-is-german-spoken$ where-is-german-spoken.php?page_id=4  [L,QSA]

i want to excute the last rewiterule "
RewriteRule ^where-is-german-spoken$ where-is-german-spoken.php?page_id=4  [L,QSA]".

actually run the first url of RewriteRule . how can we run last RewriteRule code

Comment: What that mean You  want only run last RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

On RewriteRule the first RewriteRule  that condition is correct run if all RewriteRule's condition correct Apache run all RewriteRule, but if you want can skip RewriteRule that you don't want to run, see this for more information

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s

for see the list of flags see this page

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule